# blank text get suppressed from output file when using consecutive blank xsl:text

Tags: xslt, saxon

I've been trying to solve an issue without any success and by trial I came down to this small XSLT to prove my point. Part of the issue is this works fine on my PC, but when running on the server the output is different. I was able to pin point the issue to the fact that the XSLT is writing two consecutive `xsl:text` which are both blanks.

The problem is when there is two consecutive blanks, one of the two get suppressed. For the inquiring mind, I'm actually writing a MARCXML file using the LOC MODS to MARC XSLT and the issue is with CP 7-10 and CP 11-14 for the 008 field.  When both are blank, there's only 4 blanks instead of 8 which makes the loading fail.

Here's the XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>beginning of a string</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>end of a string</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

The result is as follow:

```
beginning of a string    end of a string
```

Note there's only 4 spaces instead of 8.  If I insert text in any of the two blank XSLT text, everything is fine.  And again, this gets outputted fine on my PC, but not on the server.

**Does anyone know if there's an option or configuration of Saxon which needs to get set for this to output properly?**

I use Liquid Studio to test my XSLT locally on my computer using the same input file as the one on the server. On the server, the transformation gets executed by command line and we are using Saxon HE9.9. I download and look at the resulting XML on my PC using Liquid Studio.

Here's the command line : `D:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.9N\bin\Transform" -s:"\\fileshare.lacaws02.local\goanywhere\data\Test008\mods2marc-In 2.xml" -xsl:\\fileshare.lacaws02.local\goanywhere\Lib\MODS\MODS3-4_TO_MARC21slim_XSLT16.xsl -o:\\fileshare.lacaws02.local\goanywhere\userdata\workspace\1000000000114\Output.xml`

Comment: Curious if you have tried using a single `<xsl:text>` element with 8 spaces to see whether they are all preserved, just to see if there is a difference?

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen yes that would work, but the code I'm dealing with is a lot more complex than this and it is unfortunatly not a possibility.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just looking to help further categorize the issue and demonstrate that it is not collapsing a whitespace for a single `<xsl:text>` but only consecutive text elements that are whitespace-only.

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly it.  Furthermore, I did another test with an third blank (4 spaces) xslt:text and again only 4 characters came out.

Comment: It always helps if you tell us all details like the exact version of Saxon used (are the versions the same on your system and the server?), how exactly you run the XSLT and look at the transformation result (e.g. command line, Java code, IDE editor).

Comment: I use Liquid Studio to test my XSLT locally on my computer using the same input file as the one on the server. On the server, the transformation gets executed by command line and we are using Saxon HE9.9.  I download and look at the resulting XML on my PC using Liquid Studio.

Comment: Here's the command line : D:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.9N\bin\Transform" -s:"\\fileshare.lacaws02.local\goanywhere\data\Test008\mods2marc-In 2.xml" -xsl:\\fileshare.lacaws02.local\goanywhere\Lib\MODS\MODS3-4_TO_MARC21slim_XSLT16.xsl -o:\\fileshare.lacaws02.local\goanywhere\userdata\workspace\1000000000114\Output.xml

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the Java platform. Is it possible to eliminate the step "I download and look at the resulting XML on my PC using Liquid Studio." to eliminate the possibility that that step is changing the file? Also, Are you using output method text or xml, and is this the entire stylesheet?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKay.  It is a protected environment and I can only browse and download files using a web browser, but I know for a fact this is actually a problem as it creates a problem trying to load a file.  This is actually a problem from a stylesheet from Library of Congress that I'm using for converting a MODS XML file to a MARCXML file.  The style sheet has approx 2600 lines which I thought was too big/complex to share.  The only difference I can see is Liquid Studio is using Saxon HE 9.8 wheras my version on the server is Saxon HE 9.9.  BTW, I bought your book!  :)

Comment: I'm using output method XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got our admin to install Saxon HE 9.8 on our server and ran the same file with the same XSLT and everything is working. Therefore, I'm suspecting this is a bug with Saxon HE 9.9. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: It's very frustrating to me to see this problem "resolved" by moving to an earlier release: that's not a resolution, it's a workaround. Please, if you can, raise a bug report at saxonica.plan.io and supply enough information for us to locate and fix the bug. You can send any repro material direct to Saxonica using the contact information on our web site. (Incidentally, 2600 lines is quite a small stylesheet compared with some of the ones we have to investigate.)